# Meteor import error: createApolloServer is not a function

Tags: meteor, apollo, apollo-server

So I'm attempting to get an Apollo server working with an existing Meteor project. In my project directory, I ran

```
meteor add apollo
meteor npm install --save apollo-client graphql-server-express express graphql 
graphql-tools body-parser
```

to add Apollo to my project and install all the dependencies I'll need later. When I attempt to create my Apollo server in my imports/startup/index.js file, I get the error

```
TypeError: createApolloServer is not a function
```

I know this means that the function is not importing correctly, but I'm not sure why the package wouldn't be available in my code since I added it. Am I missing something obvious?

import/startup/index.js

```
import { createApolloServer } from 'meteor/apollo';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

createApolloServer({});
```

Comment: What documentation are you using? if you refer to https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started.html it says `const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');` and later `const server = new ApolloServer({ typeDefs, resolvers });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API has changed in the current v3 of `meteor/apollo`:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/meteor.html#Server

Answer (score 1):

In .meteor/packages, make sure you are using Apollo@2.0.0